# Using Dashes in Ruby on Rails Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller product_types_controller.rb.  I want to use dashes (-) instead of _ for my page names.  Is there a way to format actions on a large scale so that page names contain dashes instead of underscores in them?  I don't care about the naming inside the file structure.  This is for Rails 2.3.8.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override your to_params method.
http://www.jroller.com/obie/entry/seo_optimization_of_urls_in